# query 2 tables based on third main table

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get my head wrapped around JOINS.
I have tried a multitude of joins with no success.

Consider the following tables:

Allsongs

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Artist | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Title  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

several different artist tables: ie Elvis, Beatles etc

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Songid | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The Songid field in the artist tables is identical to the allsongs.id field

I am trying to create a query that  will join the following queries into one query

```
select s.title from allsongs s
join beatles b ON s.id = b.songid;

select s.title from allsongs s
join elvis e ON s.id = e.songid;
```

I thought this might work:

```
select s.title from allsongs s
join beatles b ON s.id = b.songid
join elvis e ON s.id = e.songid;
```

but it gives: Empty set.

If I use Left outer join it does what I want as long as I limit the the number of rows manually

I hope I am being clear enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a union. Both queries need to return the same number of columns with the same order of data types. The column names come from the first select statement, in case you want to do an order by or anything like that afterwards.

```
(select s.title from allsongs s
join beatles a ON s.id = a.songid)
union all
(select s.title from allsongs s
join elvis a ON s.id = a.songid);
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked except for one problem. It turns out one of the titles was with both artists, consequently it only returned one of them. Would there be a way around that or is it that simply due to the table structures?

Comment: Change it to `UNION ALL` instead of union. That will show duplicate rows.